Connection to SQL Server database using SSH tunnel from another country does not work
I have a tricky problem.
I had a working connection to a SQL Server database using a SSH tunnel in my home country, but when I traveled to another country, it does not work anymore. I haven't changed anything but it still doesn't work. Even when I am using VPN.
Error:

Can't initialize tunnel
Cannot establish tunnel to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
Cannot establish tunnel to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
Connect timed out

What could be the problem?
My colleague had same issue and we compared every field 1:1 when I was in my home country and connection worked for me. We did not solve it back then.

so you can't tell what's wrong. The IP address you use may fall into some filter. Another option is to have a firewall that blocks access from addresses that are not registered in your country.

@mrmcwolf  Thanks for reply.
The IP address you use may fall into some filter - this can be fixed in server side? Because I am not the owner of that db.
[..]firewall that blocks access from addresses that are not registered in your country - what are the options here?

The country you are in may have some policy that blocks the connection to the address you are trying to reach. There is nothing to do here but check your local law for such a policy. On the other hand, the server administrator may have imposed restrictions on which addresses you can access it from. If this is the reason, you can talk to it, allow access from the network you are currently using, or you can use a VPN to "enter" your country and use the ssh tunnel through it.

If it's not a problem, can you share the IP address of the server and I can check if I can reach it from my country. That way you'll at least know where the restriction is.

@mrmcwolf thanks for options but the problem is a bit different now. I don't know why but now the connection error message is like this: "The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 49266 has failed. Error: "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2005 or later.". ClientConnectionId..."
If I click on test tunnel connection it show it connected.

But if I click on test connection it is not working

most likely the sql server itself is down (or listening on a different port).
